# Ant Design React - How do I turn on multiple mode of autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, tagging, antd

I need autocomplete to be able to select more than one value - this should be called multiple/tagging mode and I see in the docs they mention it:

> allowClear    Show clear button, effective in multiple mode only.

Comment: you can use Selector element with mode="tags"  or "multiple" https://ant.design/components/select/#components-select-demo-multiple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per ant docs, Autocomplete doesn't have mode property. So it doesn't support multiple selection though they mentioned multiple mode in allowclear property(may be copy pasted from other feature and haven't corrected it).

You can use select tag with `mode="tags"` to support multiple selection, But you have to load autocomplete data as children, whereas autocomplete has datasource property.

***Or you can ask for the feature in ant design repo***